# Popup with edit action not working in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have popup which is opened using:

```
<%= link_to user.username, "/users/"+user.id.to_s+"/edit", :method => :post, :target=> "_blank" %>
```

**edit.html.erb file is:**

```
<div id="dvUserMgmt" class="popup">
<%= form_for(:user, :url => { :controller => 'users', :action => 'update'}) do |f| %>
<table>
 <tr>
   <td class="labelfield">*Name</td>
   <td class="textfield">
    <input type="text" name="tb_realname" value=<%= @realname %> />
   </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td class="buttons" colspan="3">             
    <%= submit_tag 'Update', :url => { :controller => 'users', :action => 'update'}, :class => 'popup_closebox' %>
    <%= tag :input, :type => 'button', :value => 'Cancel', :class => 'popup_closebox' %>
   </td>
 </tr>
</table>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Upon clicking update button, the action update is not getting executed.
Can anyone point where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of code is not written the Rails way, let's correct it and see if it changes your result.

1) correct your line, but explain wh you have a post method for an edit?

```
<%= link_to user.username, edit_user_path(user), :method => :post, :target=> "_blank" %>
```

2) Rails knows your entry already exists, I guess `@user` is defined

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
```

3) use the form helpers:

```
<%= f.submit 'Update', :class => 'popup_closebox' %>
```

4) Provide your params to help debugging.